# How to concatenate the low halves of two SSE registers?

Tags: optimization, x86, sse, simd

I have two SSE registers and I want to replace the high half of one by the low half of the other. As usual, the fastest way.

I guess it is doable by shifting one of the registers by 8 bytes, then `alignr` to concatenate.

Is there any single-instruction solution?

Comment: `movlhps`, not sure about bypass delays though

Comment: @harold Thanks, I can try that.

Comment: @Harold: mh, I am stuck because I am using the intrisincs syntax and my data is integer. Casts aren't possible.

Comment: Yes they are:  `_mm_castsi128_ps` and `_mm_castps_si128` are reinterpret-casts that emit no instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`punpcklqdq`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PUNPCKLBW:PUNPCKLWD:PUNPCKLDQ:PUNPCKLQDQ.html) to combine the low halves of two registers into hi:lo in a single register.  This is identical to what the `movlhps` FP instruction does, and also `unpcklpd`, but operates in the integer domain on CPUs that care about FP vs. integer shuffles for bypass delays.

---

**Bonus reading: combining different parts of two registers**

`palignr` would only be good for combining `hi:xxx` with `xxx:lo`, to produce `lo:hi` (i.e. reversed).  You can use an FP shuffle (the register-register form of `movsd`) to get `hi:lo` (by moving the low half of `xxx:lo` to replace the low garbage in `hi:xxx`).  Without that, you'd want to use `punpckhqdq` to bring the high half of one register to the low half, then use `punpcklqdq` to combine the low halves of two registers.

On most CPUs other than Intel Nehalem, floating-point shuffles on integer data are generally fine (little or no extra latency when used between vector-integer ALU instructions).  On Nehalem, you might get two cycles of extra latency into and out of a floating point shuffle (for a total of 4 cycles latency), but that's only a big problem for throughput if it's part of a loop-carried dependency chain.  See [Agner Fog's guides](http://agner.org/optimize/) for more info.

Agner's Optimizing Assembly guide also has a whole section of tables of SSE/AVX instructions that are useful for various kinds of data movement within or between registers.  See the [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) tag wiki for a link, download the PDF, read section 13.7 "Permuting data" on page 130.

To use FP shuffles with intrinsics, you have to clutter up your code with `_mm_castsi128_ps` and `_mm_castps_si128`, which are reinterpret-casts that emit no instructions.

Comment: It seems that PUNPCKLQDQ does exactly what I need: Destination[0..63] = Destination[0..63];
  Destination[64..127] = Source[0..63];

Comment: @YvesDaoust: fixed to properly answer the question :P